# Chrome Extension gets rejected because of "Permissions" but they are as narrow as they get to

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, permissions, manifest, chrome-web-store

I am developing a Google Chrome Web Store Extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dkegpejgfhckgkekkgjjbpmhijdeomac) that simply gets the user selected text and appends it to a URL when the extension is selected in the context menu (right-click over text).
My **manifest.json** is as simple as it can:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "__MSG_appName__",
  "description": "__MSG_appDesc__",
  "version": "0.3",
  "default_locale": "en_US",
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "open_in_tab": false
  },

  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "WhatsApp-icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "storage"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "WhatsApp-icon.png",
    "32": "WhatsApp-icon.png",
    "48": "WhatsApp-icon.png",
    "128": "WhatsApp-icon.png"
  }  
}
```

It is getting rejected because of "User Data Privacy - **Use of Permissions**", however, I believe the problem does not rely on the "**permissions**" section of the **manifest.json**, as it is really short, narrow and include very inoffensive items. 
While publishing, I get the message saying that it can take more time because it requests "**Broad Host Permissions**". That is true: although I do not have any wide URL pattern set in the code, it is supposed to work in every website the user wants.
Do you still think the "**permissions**" has something to do with the rejection or the problem relies in the "**background**" section? What could be causing it? Thank you!

Comment: This is a problem of the review process in the web store being vague and anti-human, not a programming problem so this is off-topic here. Try asking on a Google's product forum like [this one](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-extensions), preferably attach your extension or post a link to the source repository.

Comment: Will do, thank you!

Comment: I got approved!